# Do not parse response when data is empty for a key

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model like this, in this scenario in failure case my data can be empty and there will be an error in response. Something like this. With this in API failure case as  Message model has keys which have non-null value the parsing is failing as data key is empty. How we can handle this case?

```
{
  "data": {
  },
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    {
  
    }
  ]
}

@JsonSerializable()
class MessageResponse {
  factory MessageResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MessageResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MessageResponseToJson(this);

  @JsonKey(name: "data")
  late Message data;
  @JsonKey(name: "errors")
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> errors;

  MessageResponse(
    this.data,
    this.success,
    this.errors,
  );
}
class Message {
  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MessageFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MessageToJson(this);

  @JsonKey(name: "id")
  late String id;

}
```

Comment: You could just make the `data` attribute null-able.

Answer (score 0):

As per this (closed) [issue](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/538), there is no way to achieve this.

If you have control over the response (the backend), try returning null when you have error(s) and use `@JsonKey(includeIfNull: true)` for the `data` key.

Otherwise, you can write your own class [extending the JsonConverter class](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#custom-types-and-custom-encoding). [Refer this example](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/blob/master/example/lib/json_converter_example.dart).